# How can I use keys to navigate between words separated by underscores?

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts, netbeans-8

In programming for Drupal, much of what I do is pass function names within strings.

I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> arrow and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> arrow to navigate through the string, but NetBeans does not recognize the underscores as separating words inside strings.  Because of this, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+arrow movements only take me to the beginning or ending of the string.

NetBeans supports navigation based on Camel notation. Is there any way to make it give similar support for underscores?

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=197253